# Как передать массив цифровых значений в параметр PL/SQL процедуры из Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, plsql

В Delphi использую `UniConnection.ExecProcEx`
В PL/SQL тип входного аргумента процедуры - ассоциативный массив, например `type mytype is table of positive`;

Comment: Передать строкой, а в процедуре обработать - не вариант?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через `UniConnection.ExecProcEx` передать такого типа данные нельзя.

Для работы с такими типами у компонентов *Devart* требуется писать довольно много кода.

Посмотрите их примеры от компонентов *ODAC*. В этих примерах несколько способов работы с разными типами массивов.